# Html5 form validation checkboxes

Tags: html, checkbox

I want to make only one checkbox of a group of checkboxes mandatory for the user to check without using JavaScript. I have the following (quite simple) code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_condition" name="checkboxGroupName" id="first" required>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_condition" name="checkboxGroupName" id="first" required>
```

I want to compel visitor to select one checkbox from the group. How can I do that without JavaScript? I would appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: A little more code for context may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your `checkbox` to `radio` - radio buttons have the built in function you are looking for, in your `css` you can make the `radio button` look like a check box. see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pcvwwjoe/2/

```
<input type="radio" class="checkbox_condition" name="checkboxGroupName" id="first" required>
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox_condition" name="checkboxGroupName" id="first">
```

also, notice that since both radio buttons have the same name, you only need to use required once since they are all grouped together.